# Create a TXT File with PHP that contains all Data (*) FROM a Table

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, file-put-contents

I am trying to create a TXT file with PHP. This works fine. Unfortunately, it seems that I do not have the correct syntax, because there is no content inserted using the `file_put_contents` function to put the data from my SQLite table into the TXT file.

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('sshTunnel.sqlite');
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM mydata');

$file = 'D:\test.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $results);
?>
```

The file is written, but it contains `0 Bytes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are rows, `$results` will contain an SQLite3Result object. You still need to loop over the result set to get the data.

For example:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    file_put_contents($file, implode(', ', $row), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Note that this is just an example, there are dedicated functions to write CSV if you need that.

Comment: Great, it seems to work. The results are unformatted. Is there a short way to write the content structured?

Comment: Again, if you dump the `$row` object you can see how it is structured internally, and format any fields it may contain to your choice of structure.

Comment: How about tabs? And at the moment, I even get those, which have been deleted by now. How can that be?

Comment: @gpuk360 if they're in the results, they're not deleted. They may be soft deleted though.

Comment: @apokryfos You are right. This problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try output buffering:

```
ob_start() ;
var_dump($results) ;
file_put_contents($file, ob_get_clean()) ;
```

Comment: `$results` will contain a boolean or a SQLite3Result object.

Comment: I've dumped a variety of database result objects (never specifically a SQLite3Result) using this method.  The output is always intelligible.  However, your looping method gives fine control over how the file is structured.  So, output buffering if you want a quick and dirty look at the data, looping if you want to use the file as input to another process or as a CSV or whatever.